# Got an error when building spring security from source

Tags: java, gradle, spring-security, compilation

I need to build spring security from source for my experiments. I ran the command `$./gradlew install` folloing its guide in github[github: spring-security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security). However, it returns the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':spring-security-config:compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':spring-security-config:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10.
     Required by:
         project :spring-security-config
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.4.10/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.10.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.4.10/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.10.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.4.10.
     Required by:
         project :spring-security-config
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.4.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.4.10/kotlin-bom-1.4.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.4.10/kotlin-bom-1.4.10.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3m 53s
```

What is the cause? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is there in Gradle error:

> Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

The project is trying to resolve dependencies using https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot which being rejected with a `401` HTTP status.

It is likely failing because of the recent restrictions put in place by the Spring infrastructure team. See the blog post for more details: https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020

A potential solution is modifying the project's repositories so that public repositories such as Maven Central or JCenter are used. See Gradle's [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) for more details.

There is no guarantees if this will work if the Spring Security build requires artifacts that are only available in now private Spring repositories.