# Cannot access repo.spring.io - Getting unauthorized

Tags: spring-io

I'm working on a gradle based spring boot project which downloads some dependencies from 'repo.spring.io'. The application used to work fine a while back but now I'm seeing an error in the download dependencies stage.

When the application goes on to download https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, I receive an error with HTTP response code 401(Unauthorized).

I'm not sure if there has been some recent change at repo.spring.io end as this used to work on my application before without any issues.

This is the exact error that I get for reference --

```html
What went wrong:
19:44:19 A problem occurred configuring project ':account_settings-service'.
19:44:19 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':account_settings-service:classpath'.
19:44:19    > Could not download commons-logging.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3)
19:44:19       > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar'.
19:44:19          > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Kindly help if anyone has any idea about this or has observed a similar issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Tried hitting the same link using browser as well. But the browser too displays a pop up to enter username and password which I don't find anywhere, nor in the recent release notes for repo.spring.io

Comment: I also am getting this issue, and don't have any explanation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839144/got-an-error-when-building-spring-security-from-source seems relevant.

Answer (score 6):

As per this answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839144/got-an-error-when-building-spring-security-from-source), the Spring team are [putting the kibbosh](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020) on freeloaders using their repository as a public distribution channel.

It looks like you'll need to adjust your `{build thingy}` so that it does *not* attempt to download from https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/

In the case of `commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3` being an Apache project, 'Maven Central' (aka https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/, being an Apache repository) hosts https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/ without restrictions.

Comment: Note: I was in a similar position just now.  I discovered that https://mvnrepository.com/ is only a meta-directory (ad-supported), and you can tell which repositories host various packages by inspecting the 'Repositories' tags for the entry: eg. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2 in your case.  And click on any of the repository 'tags' to browse the 'actual URL' of the repository.

Comment: In my case, https://mvnrepository.com did not know that the artifact I needed was actually in the 'JFrog Bintray JCentral' repo, and 'just trying' worked for me (phew!)

Answer (score 3):

moving to spring-boot it required a pluginRepositories entry with spring-releases repo in the pom, to get the plugin, but then hit this same 401 error.
Adding maven-central pluginRepository fixed it.
final entry in pom is:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mavencentral</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```