# How can I import a library from Spring Plugins Repo

Tags: maven, gradle

I (for security/infastraucture reasons) need to use [version 5.5.0 of the net.sf.dozer:dozer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.dozer/dozer?repo=springio-plugins-release) library. This version seems to only exist in the Spring Plugins repository. How can I use this particular version in gradle (other than downloading the jar myself)?

When I try to import into my build.gradle file with the following:

```
implementation('net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.0')
...
maven {
    url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/'
}
```

I get an authentication error:

```
Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/net/sf/dozer/dozer/5.5.0/dozer-5.5.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Similar problem, can you please check the solution from the given link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839144/got-an-error-when-building-spring-security-from-source

Comment: Simply use central repository ...because in the meantime the access to the spring repos has been limited...

Comment: Neither solution works because the 5.5.0 version of this library isn't available in the maven central repository (or any other public repositories)